# Handling the OPTIONS method request with Flask rest api`

Tags: jquery, python, flask-restful

I am sending post requests to the rest-api written in Flask using jquery. Along with the post request an options request is also being sent and the app is not functioning the desired way.

But when I send the same from Postman of Curl, it produces the results fine. I think I should be handling the request method for 'options' but I am not sure how to do it.

Can any one help me?

Comment: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.Flask.add_url_rule claims that as of Flask 0.6, OPTIONS should be handled automatically, and that should also work for the `@app.route` decorator - are you using an earlier version of Flask?

Comment: No I am using the 0.12 version