# Flask-RESTplus CORS request not adding headers into the response

Tags: python, rest, flask

I have an issue trying to setup CORS for my REST API. 
I'm currently using the [Flask-Restplus](https://github.com/noirbizarre/flask-restplus) package. Here's what my endpoints look like :

```
@api_ns.route('/some/endpoint')
@api_ns.response(code=400, description='Bad Request.')
class AEndpointResource(Resource):

    @api_ns.param(**api_req_fields.POST_DOC)
    @api_ns.expect(POST_REQUIRED_BODY)
    @api_ns.marshal_with(code=201,
                     fields=my_api_models.MyEndpointResponse.get_serializer(),
                     description=my_api_models.MyEndpointResponse.description)
    def post(self) -> Tuple[my_api_models.MyEndpointResponse, int]:
        """
        The post body
        """
        # Some logic here
        return response, 200
```

If I code a small javascript snippet and I try to launch it in a browser, I will get an error because there's no CORS headers. I'm seeing the Flask-Restplus is already handling the OPTIONS request without me telling him anything. (This makes sense according to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44221840/handling-the-options-method-request-with-flask-rest-api), mentioning that since Flask 0.6, the OPTIONS requests are handled automatically)

My problem is that even when I try to decorate my endpoint using :

```
from flask-restplus import cors   # <--- Adding this import

...
class AnEndpointResource(Resource):
    ...
    @my_other_decorators
    ...
    @cors.crossdomain(origin='*')  # <--- Adding this new decorator on my endpoint
    def post(self) -> Tuple[my_api_models.MyEndpointResponse, int]:
        ...
```

Nothing changes and I still get the same result as before. I get an HTTP 200 from the OPTIONS request automatically handled as before, but I don't see my new headers (i.e. Access-Control-Allow-Origin) in the response.

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 4):

Using [Flask-CORS](https://flask-cors.readthedocs.io/), it works:

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restplus import Resource, Api, fields
from flask_cors import CORS

# configuration
DEBUG = True

# instantiate the app
app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)
app.config.from_object(__name__)

# enable CORS
CORS(app, resources={r'/*': {'origins': '*'}})
```

Answer (score 3):

When doing local testing on my laptop and in my browser, I was able to solve the cors problem by adding the header in the response.

before: `return state, 200`

after: `return state, 200, {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'}`

Comment: Thanks @user985366. This was the only way I've found to enable CORS for a `flask_restplus` route that uses [response marshalling](https://flask-restplus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/marshalling.html)

Answer (score 0):

I tested and the headers you are looking for are added to the response to the subsequent `GET` request. The decorator `@cors.crossdomain` has an option `automatic_options` which is set to be `True` by default. This means your OPTIONS request will still be handled automatically.

See [this](https://github.com/noirbizarre/flask-restplus/blob/master/tests/test_cors.py#L37) test to check how it should work.

The `flask_restplus.cors` module is not documented so not sure if you should use it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a CORS problem as well and solved it [this way](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.Flask.after_request):

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restplus import Api

app = Flask('name')
api = Api(app)

// your api code here


@app.after_request
def after_request(response):
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    return response
```

Comment: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.Flask.after_request
after_request needs to return a response object..

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that flask-restplus only assigns CORS headers to the GET request. When the browser makes an OPTIONS request, this method isn't handled by a method on the `Resource` class. Then you get a flickering CORS header: one request it works, the next it doesn't, etc

When a 404 is raised, this also skips the CORS decorator.

A workaround for these bugs is using something like:

```
def exception_to_response(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def _exc_to_resp_decorator(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
        except Exception as e:
            return self.api.handle_error(e)

    return _exc_to_resp_decorator


@api.route("/your-endpoint")
class SomeEndpoint(Resource):
    @cors.crossdomain(origin='*')
    def options(self):
        # Make sure the OPTIONS request is also handled for CORS
        # The "automatic_options" will handle this, no need to define a return here:
        return

    @api.expect(my_schema)
    @api.response(200, "Success")
    @cors.crossdomain(origin='*')
    @exception_to_response
    def get(self):
        return {"json-fields": 123}, 200
```